# Flash message background color not disappearing after Refreshing the page redirected to

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

When I edit a post I get the flash message as expected in my laravel project but after refreshing the page I redirect to only the text disappears and the background color remains. What could be the problem?

My code in my controller in my update() function is:
`return redirect(route('post.index'))->with('flash', 'Post Edited Successfully');`

My code in my .blade.php file is:

`<h4 class="alert alert-info" >{{ session('flash') }}</h4>`

Comment: if you are still displaying that `<h4>` whether there is a flash message or not, it could have styling ... you probably don't want to have the `<h4>` in the markup at all if there is no session flash message

Comment: @lagbox I'm not sure if you have addressed my challenge. Is the tag the problem I replace it with a div? NB; I'm a beginner trying to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `h4` tag always remains either there is a flash message or not. When there is a message its displaying the message but when there's none h4 tag is showing with empty value and the background is coming from that. you need to check if there a flash message.

```
@if (session('flash'))
    <h4 class="alert alert-info" >{{ session('flash') }}</h4>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

In your Controller :

```
return redirect(route('post.index'))->withSuccess('Post Edited Successfully');
```

In your blade :

```
@if(Session::has('success') )
   <h4 class="alert alert-info" >{{ session()->get('success')}}</h4>
@endif
```